# Handling user registration in an Ember.js/Rails/Devise app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ember.js

I'm playing around with writing a pure Ember.js app on top of Rails 4 and **I'm puzzled how user management is handled**. My original idea was to use pure server-rendered templates (ERB) to do the user registration and login via Devise, and then the rest of the app would use the Ember framework.

The problem with that is that Ember wants to take over the <body> tag and control the entire viewport. In this way I can't pick and choose which aspects of the app should use server-rendered Erb templates and which should live in the Ember logic.

I see plenty of examples of how to deal with a user that's already logged-in and [ember-auth](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth) looks interesting to facilitate authentication-aware controllers, but I've seen no tutorials or suggestions on allowing the full user signup experience to take place in the Ember app.

**Am I missing something, either from a technical perspective where I just haven't found the right code or from a architectural perspective where I shouldn't be doing it this way?**

This is with ember-rails (0.12.0 w/1.0.0.rc3.3 ember-source), Rails 4.0.0.rc1, and Devise (rails4 branch).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ember-auth`](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com) dev here.

You don't actually need any special treatment for user sign up. Treat user sign up as you would for another model, in the sense that creating a `user` model will not require authentication. (Editing it or deleting it should require authentication though.)

Your implementation might look like:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  email: DS.attr 'string'
  password: DS.attr 'string'

App.UsersNewRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.User.createRecord()

App.UsersNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend 
  create: ->
    @store.commit()
```

Error-checking, template code, etc, skipped for brevity.

Comment: Ah- my philosophy was skewed and I didn't realize the problem was simpler than it appeared. I think I became blinded by how intricate Devise's server-side solution is with the myriad views/specialty controllers/etc. Thanks!

Comment: So after the account is created and the server responds with the user + auth token how do we automatically sign in to ember-auth?

Comment: @heartsentwined if you could answer @flynfish 's question I'd appreciate it! I have the same question.  Is there a way to stuff `ember-auth` with a token without specifically having `ember-auth` call the API endpoint?

Comment: Valid use case. I'll make a proper public API later when I have time. For now:
1. give `ember-auth` a JSON, same as one that you would have returned from a `POST /sign-in` call: `App.Auth.get('_response').canonicalize(json);`
2. send a `signInSuccess` event: `App.Auth.trigger('signInSuccess');`

Comment: @heartsentwined @Brandon That worked, I set it on the `didCreate` method of the User model:

`didCreate: function(model) { App.Auth.get('_response').canonicalize(model); App.Auth.trigger('signInSuccess');
  }`

Comment: @Brandon no problem. My api returns the user as the json response, so check out my answer for the updated code.

Comment: Update for googlers: in the latest version (`9.x`), you can call `this.get('auth').createSession()` and `this.get('auth').destroySession)` inside routes, controllers, and views.

Comment: I think for security you should not make the password part of the user model. And also delete it from the client after sending it to the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is here for reference to what worked based off of @heartsentwined's answer since pasting in comments doesn't work very well. See the comments for more info. Since my api returns the user json I just pass in the format its expecting.

```
didCreate: function() {
  var user = App.Auth.get('_response').response.user;
  var auth = {auth_token: user.auth_token, id: user.id};
  App.Auth.get('_response').canonicalize(auth);
  App.Auth.trigger('signInSuccess');
}
```

UPDATE:
I switched to ember-model and now do this in the same place that I call `model.save()` (the `submit` action of SignupController).

```
var model = this.get('model'); 
model.on('didCreateRecord', function() { 
  var user = this.data;
  var auth = {auth_token: user.auth_token, user_id: user.id, remember_token: user.remember_token};
  App.Auth.get('_response').canonicalize(auth);
  App.Auth.trigger('signInSuccess');
}); 

model.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions above ALMOST but not quite worked for me. Here is what did work:

```
didCreate: function() {
  var user = App.Auth.get('_response').response.user;
  App.Auth.signIn({
    data: {
      'email':    user.email,
      'password': this.get('password'),
      'remember': true
    }
  });
}
```

App.Auth.signIn is used in the documentation explicitly: http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/docs